# Force an object to to be indexed by its id on parent dictionary

Tags: typescript, dictionary

I have item objects containing an `id` property, and a dictionary of said items. I want to type it such that each item must be indexed by its id property on the parent dictionary.

I expected this to do the job:

```
type Item<K extends string = string> = { id: K }
type Dictionary = { [K in string]: Item<K> }

const dict: Dictionary = { abc: { id: 'xyz' } }
```

[**Playground link here**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsA8BpKEAe8B2ATAzlPsAE4CW2A5lALxGkWUB8tUA3lGbgFxRoC+AKFCQoAETIBjYGQD22AIYkQrDgG00FeuSoBdXnESoWQwZPnEouKcF4TpcxctVQFAI0m8OXXgHJcEABmvlD8oUA)

I expected this to result in an error, since `"abc"` !== `"xyz"`, but TypeScript doesn't seem to care. How come? And how do I achieve my goal?

Comment: `K in string` does not map over all possible strings individually; it's just `string`, making `Dictionary` equivalent to `{[x: string]: {id: string}}`, which is why it behaves the way it's behaving.   There is no specific type in TypeScript corresponding to your desired set of values.  You can make a generic constraint with a helper function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mL4jZm), though.  Does that meet your needs?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: I was looking more for a way to constrain the type globally, rather than on creation, but if I understand you correctly, this cannot be done, so I'll just go without it. Thank you very much for your help again, @jcalz, you are true stackoverflow hero :)